# Regression Analysisfor targets

Tags: regression

I have the data for the target for next two month with 2 independent variable as seasonal variability1(sv1) and seasonal variability2(sv2) are of 180 and 185 days respectively.but  i have the  values of 100 days of targets as dependent variable  and sv1 and sv2 are available of 180 and 185 as they are considered categorical. then  of sv1 sv2 then  what is the number to take as total values available to calculate mean,variance as for sv1,sv2,and targets. for predictions of remaining 2 month  ion sv1